# in which order to install cu and language packs on different servers?

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, update

I am using the script from this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2013/04/01/why-sharepoint-2013-cumulative-update-takes-5-hours-to-install/) to update SharePoint 2013 environment on web and app server.

The environment contains a language pack already, Dutch. The script is installing the CUs at this moment.

Do I need to install language packs again after I have installed the CU of December 2017 or do I leave it as is?

Please, it is urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As a short answer:** No need to reinstall the Language Pack again after installing the CU,

> **Note:** After installing the CU, you will need to run the SharePoint Configuration wizard on all Sharepoint servers within the farm started
>   from the SharePoint server that hosts the central administration to
>   apply these updates!

Comment: Thanks Mohamed for your quick reply. Just to be clear I understand you correctly. The language pack is of 2016 I think. Now I am applying the CUs of 2017. So, do I need to update the Language which was already installed?

Comment: No, bro no need to reinstall it again as I mentioned! but if you need to install update for language pack, try to install Language Pack Service Pack 1 if it's not installed, to check if it installed or not,  go to Central Administration > upgrade and migration > check product and patch, check the build number beside the SP 2013 Language pack, if the build number less than "15.0.4569.1506" so you can install the LP SP1 for your language from here https://www.microsoft.com/nl-be/download/details.aspx?id=42082 :)

Comment: Thanks bro!!! But what is the difference between "15.0.4569.1506" and this: 15.0.4823.1003? I believe the later is the latest, right?

Comment: The later is newer than `15.0.4569.1506`  but not the latest, the `15.0.4823.1003` is May 2016 update.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Yes, that's what I meant actually. Just the nerves :)

Comment: you are welcome brother :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont to install the language pack again if you are applying the CU to the farm. CU include the fix for language packs as well.

After installing the CU simply run the COnfig wizard on all servers in the farm one by one.

Only time you need to apply the separate update for language pack is the Service pack.